# Custom Slick Arrows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I am using Slick.js with my project and I want the buttons and dots to be inside the div. I've tried using putting a selector of the div  on the javascript but whenever I do that button doesn't work. I've change some css code and I could put the next button inside the image but it seems that the previous button is being displayed below the image on the slick. I'm not sure why this happen. Thank you.

```js
$('.sliding-announcement').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 100,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    prevArrow: '<button class="button-slider slide-arrow prev-arrow"></button>',
  nextArrow: '<button class="button-slider slide-arrow next-arrow"></button>',
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

```css
.button-slider{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.slide-arrow{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.prev-arrow{
    background: red;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #113463;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
.next-arrow{
    background: red;
  right: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 0 solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #113463;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 
 
<div class="sliding-announcement">

    <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
        <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/789/536/354.jpg?hmac=bACXXOVJWzwDX0UtvGkk0xqXo1F2fk2N9XxBgPW6Jwg">
    </div>
    <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
        <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/789/536/354.jpg?hmac=bACXXOVJWzwDX0UtvGkk0xqXo1F2fk2N9XxBgPW6Jwg">
    </div>
    <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
        <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/789/536/354.jpg?hmac=bACXXOVJWzwDX0UtvGkk0xqXo1F2fk2N9XxBgPW6Jwg">
    </div>
    <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
        <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/789/536/354.jpg?hmac=bACXXOVJWzwDX0UtvGkk0xqXo1F2fk2N9XxBgPW6Jwg">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ***buttons and dots to be inside the div***, inside which ```div```?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the images aren't included in the previous post, I've edited the post with images I found online. The problem that I have is that the previous button for the slick carousel is not at the top of the slick images unlike the next button which can be seen at the top of the image. I am trying to put the previous button and the indicators at the top of the images. sorry for the confusion of my first post

Comment: At the top, or at the middle (height) of the slider?

Comment: Included a working example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with `pseudo` classes for this. Add a wrapper around your slider with a `relative` positioning to it so you can `absolute` position your arrows.

Below a working example:

```js
$('.sliding-announcement').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 100,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    prevArrow: $('.prev-arrow'),
    nextArrow: $('.next-arrow'),
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                infinite: true,
                dots: true
            }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
.button-slider {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

.slide-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prev-arrow {
    left: 10px;
}

.next-arrow {
    right: 10px;
}

.slide-arrow::after {
    content: '';
    background: red;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.prev-arrow::after {
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid #113463;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

.next-arrow::after {
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid #113463;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

.sliding-announcement-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 
<div class="sliding-announcement-wrap">
    <div class="sliding-announcement">

        <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
            <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/789/536/354.jpg?hmac=bACXXOVJWzwDX0UtvGkk0xqXo1F2fk2N9XxBgPW6Jwg">
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
            <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1035/536/354.jpg?hmac=N7LdfGCyj7EjI-_m2RvtgMrZ-SKgYmtwPBf_dd7ZDf8">
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
            <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/789/536/354.jpg?hmac=bACXXOVJWzwDX0UtvGkk0xqXo1F2fk2N9XxBgPW6Jwg">
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-annonuncement-image-container">
            <img class="sliding-annonuncement-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1035/536/354.jpg?hmac=N7LdfGCyj7EjI-_m2RvtgMrZ-SKgYmtwPBf_dd7ZDf8">
        </div>

    </div>

    <button class="button-slider slide-arrow prev-arrow"></button>
    <button class="button-slider slide-arrow next-arrow"></button>
</div>
```